# Извлекает текст из тегов при парсинге сайта не во всех случаях

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Решил в ознакомительных целях спарсить с сайта https://coinmarketcap.com название криптовалюты и её цену. 
Извлекает текст из тегов при парсинге сайта не во всех случаях. Более подробно описал после кода и также прикрепил скриншот.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_html(url):

    r = requests.get(url) #Responce 

    return r.text #return html code 



def get_all_links(html):

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    tds =  soup.find('table', id = 'currencies-all').find_all('td',class_='currency-name')

    links = []

    for td in tds:

        a = td.find('a').get('href')
        link = 'https://coinmarketcap.com'+ a

        links.append(link)
    return links

def get_page_data(html, index):

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

    try:
      name = soup.find('h1',class_ = 'details-panel-item--name').text.strip()
    except:
      name = ''
    try:
      price  = soup.find('span', class_ = 'h2 text-semi-bold details-panel-item--price__value').text.strip()
    except:
      price = ''

    data = {'name': name,'price' : price}

    print(index, data)
    return data

def main():
    start = datetime.now()

    url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/all/views/all/'
    all_links = get_all_links(get_html(url))

    for index,url in enumerate(all_links):
        html = get_html(url)
        data = get_page_data(html, index)    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

В функции "get_html" берём код страницы. 
В функции "get_all_links" ссылки на страничку каждой криптовалюты. 
Эти функции работают хорошо, остановился на них чтобы пояснить что делает этот код.

Проблема в функции "get_page_data".
При первом запуске мы успешно извлекаем необходимую информацию, например, по поводу первой криптовалюты в списке, но при N запуске извлечь не получается. То есть при первом запуске мы извлекаем что нужно из первой в списке криптовалюты, а при втором запуске того же кода можем не извлечь. 
Также не всегда извлекается информация в принципе. 
[image: красной стрелкой указал место, где не получилось извлечь то, что нужно. Такое присутствует не только тут. Также при следующем запуске оно может быть и в месте , которое обозначено жёлтой стрелкой. По итог определённый процент информации не получается извлечь, но при другом запуске при работе того же кода этот процент изменятся]

Буду благодарен любой информации по данной проблеме.
Если кто-то смог нагуглить, то, пожалуйста, скажите что вы вбивали.

Comment: так банально нету такого элемента на некоторых страницах

Comment: Хотя нет, там просто стоит защита. от cloudflare, это можно увидеть, если вывести r.text

Comment: Ответ на первый комментарий.
Есть. Например информация о битке. При первом запуске всё норм, но при втором может уже быть пусто.

Ответ на второй комментарий. 
Я выводил r.text - на выходе html код вроде

Comment: ну что вы спорите, выведите r.text для всех и смотрите, после n-ого запроса включается защита, и у вас уже там будет совсем другая страница, на которой этого элемента уже нет

Comment: Я понял. Спасибо)
Защиту эту обойти, кстати, не сложно. После n-й попытки сайт всё-таки даёт то, что необходимо)